# Time and date dimension in data warehouse

Tags: data-warehouse, infobright

I'm building a data warehouse. Each fact has it's `timestamp`. I need to create reports by day, month, quarter but by hours too. Looking at the examples I see that dates tend to be saved in dimension tables. [image: alt starexample]
<sub>(source: [etl-tools.info](http://etl-tools.info/images/dw_star_schema.jpg))</sub>

But I think, that it makes no sense for time. The dimension table would grow and grow. On the other hand JOIN with date dimension table is more efficient than using date/time functions in `SQL`.

What are your opinions/solutions ?

(I'm using Infobright)

Comment: Hourly reports seems kind of a high resolution for a data warehouse. Is really needed/appropriate?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My guess is that it depends on your reporting requirement.
If you need need something like

```
WHERE "Hour" = 10
```

meaning every day between 10:00:00 and 10:59:59, then I would use the time dimension, because it is faster than

```
WHERE date_part('hour', TimeStamp) = 10
```

because the date_part() function will be evaluated for every row.
You should still keep the TimeStamp in the fact table in order to aggregate over boundaries of days, like in:

```
WHERE TimeStamp between '2010-03-22 23:30' and '2010-03-23 11:15'
```

which gets awkward when using dimension fields.

Usually, time dimension has a minute resolution, so 1440 rows.

Comment: To be clear, you're recommending two separate dimensions, one of days (365*10 = 3,650 records) and one of minutes (1,440 records)?  I'd like to understand the advantage of splitting it up; a single `DateTime` dimension would be larger (365*10*24 = 87,600 records at an hourly grain) but still not huge, and would make time zone calculations much easier.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades by splitting it up each dimension has a sensible PK. Some facts are going to be at the date granularity (i.e. without a timestamp), and some are going to be at the time granularity. Joining a fact table at the date granularity to the dimension at time granularity is going to cause duplicates that you then need to throw more resource at to remove.

Comment: @jackohug: Sure, which is why I always have a `Dates` table and a `Times` table.  But when you *do* have date-time values, why use two keys and double join instead of a single four-byte FK to a `DateTimes` table?  It's worked fine for me, but some people seem allergic to it, for no well-explained reason.

Answer (score 33):

Kimball recommends [having separate time- and date dimensions](http://www.kimballgroup.com/2004/02/01/design-tip-51-latest-thinking-on-time-dimension-tables/):

> In previous Toolkit books, we have
> recommended building such a dimension
> with the minutes or seconds component
> of time as an offset from midnight of
> each day, but we have come to realize
> that the resulting end user
> applications became too difficult,
> especially when trying to compute time
> spans. Also, unlike the calendar day
> dimension, there are very few
> descriptive attributes for the
> specific minute or second within a
> day. If the enterprise has well
> defined attributes for time slices
> within a day, such as shift names, or
> advertising time slots, an additional
> time-of-day dimension can be added to
> the design where this dimension is
> defined as the number of minutes (or
> even seconds) past midnight. Thus this
> time-ofday dimension would either have
> 1440 records if the grain were minutes
> or 86,400 records if the grain were
> seconds.

Comment: @davek is it necessary to keep a datetime column in the fact table as another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2517075/7887590) states? Since when filter time window like `between '2010-03-22 23:30' and '2010-03-23 11:15' ` is really not good to operate with two join tables.

Answer (score 5):

Time should be a dimension on data warehouses, since you will frequently want to aggregate about it. You could use the [snowflake-Schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowflake_schema) to reduce the overhead. In general, as I pointed out in my comment, hours seem like an unusually high resolution. If you insist on them, making the hour of the day a separate dimension might help, but I cannot tell you if this is good design.

Comment: If date is a dimension for 10 years it has only about 3650 records. Hour-by-hour reports are very useful here - we need to compare days: monday to monday, tuesday to tuesday and hours monday 11:00-12:00 to tuesday 11:00-12:00.

Do you think that snowflake is more useful/efficent than star ?

Comment: Snowflake can help reduce the redundancy in the dimension-tables, but if that helps you performance- or memory-wise in your particular case I cannot say.

Comment: A date dimension with 10 years and hours is still small: 87,660 rows.  Further, you can summarize old data to reduce the time resolution.  After 10 years, how much relevance can 10AM on Thursday actually have?

Comment: depends entirely on the field, for example if i was a large Supermarket chain i would like to know peak hours history. if however i was a company making 10 to twenty sales a day i may not be all that interested in daily activity let alone hourly

Comment: How do you propose using snowflaking here?  With a primary `DateTime` dimension, which flakes out to a `Date` dimension?  These seems more cumbersome than having separate `Date` and `Time` dimensions, but I'm interested in the advantages you see.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend having seperate dimension for date and time. Date Dimension would have 1 record for each date as part of identified valid range of dates. For example: 01/01/1980 to 12/31/2025.

And a seperate dimension for time having 86400 records with each second having a record identified by the time key.

In the fact records, where u need date and time both, add both keys having references to these conformed dimensions.